# Which oil did Prophet Muhammad PBUH use?

Tags: hair, beard

I've read in various ahadith that Prophet Muhammad PBUH used oil in his head. Does anyone know which oil he used? By "which", I mean like coconut oil, argan oil, macadamia oil, almond oil etc.

Answer (score -1):

Nabi Muhammed (SAW) favourite condiments,honey,olive oil and salt and vinegar
(References only for oil)

From Hadith:

Hazrat Abu huraira (R.A.) narrated that Rasullullah (Sallallaho Alayhi Wasallam) said “Eat the olive oil and massage it over your bodies since it is a holy (mubarak) tree.”

Hazrat Alqama Bin Amir (R.A) narrates that Prophet (Sallallaho Alayhi Wasallam) said, “There is olive oil for you, eat it, massage over your body, since it is effective in Heamorrhoids (Piles).”